# 2-way edittext updates for specific use-case calculator

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on a personal project as a beginner learning kotlin for android. Im trying to make a calculator and have values update automatically in edittext's.

The question I have is lets say I have 5 edittexts (length, width, area, cost/sqft, and total cost). I would like the whole calculator to update if any of the edittext's change. (ie if width changes, the area updates. similarly, if the area is manually entered, width or length automatically change to make the whole form "correct".) I already have a basic version working that recalculates on aftertextchanged, but it currently only updates the final answer.

Would the best way to go about this be to set an aftertextchanged listener for each field and have separate functions for each field to update the other fields? Assuming width changed, the area would update, that would trigger another function to update the total cost? Is there a better way to go about this?

I'm not looking specifically for code, I've been trying to use the documentation and online tutorials to wrap my head around it, just wondering how to achieve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I got this mostly working and functional, I ended up having functions for each possible calculation (one for area from length and width, one for width using area and length, one for cost using cost/sq ft and sq ft, etc). The listeners were interesting, I used a textchanged listener only IF the edittext wasn't in focus (to handle functions outside of the current edittext) as well as functions called on loss of focus. I also set an onclicklistener on the background (enclosing) viewgroup to handle clearing focus and closing the keyboard.